# Parallel.Foreach C# random results

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to read all result from a Dataset and insert a value by Mysql, but the insert take me random result:

```
Parallel.ForEach(table, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, row =>
{
    DataRow newrow = BDDestino.newrow("Cars");

    newrow["Code"] = row["CODE"];
    newrow["Name"] = row["NAME"];

    BD.insert(newrow); 
});
```

The content of the DataSet/DataTable"table" is great, but the insert in the Mysql table is random.

If my rows are

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

The insert sometimes is: `2,3`

or: > `1,2,3`

I need ALL rows in order.

**Edit:** I thought that *Parallel.ForEach* sentences can insert whit order and very fast, but i see that *Parallel.ForEach* doesn't do it itself. Like @juharr says, this sentence maybe can be worst. Thanks to all.

Comment: The easiest way to ensure that order is to insert them sequentially from a single thread.

Comment: Because it is a parallel foreach then this is expected. Use a normal for each to garantee order.

Comment: If you *insist on parallel*, please have a look at *PLink*, i.e. `AsParallel()` and `AsOrdered()`

Comment: Whit a normal ForEach, it's work great. But i have a lot data and it take a lot of time, and i read that **Parallel.ForEach** .   Y just try `table.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().AsOrdered()`, but i have the same random result.

Comment: Are you sure that `BD` is thread safe?

Comment: If each task has to wait for the previous to finish you're not gaining anything.  In fact it's going to introduce some overhead and probably take longer.

Comment: @DavidG How can i know that? Maybe a thread block other threads that try to insert in `BD`?

Comment: Well maybe, but why do you want to do this in parallel if you need everything to be sequential?

Answer (score 1):

If you use parallelism, you cannot guarantee the order in which .insert() is called (as you found).

Somehow you need to fix that order in advance:

- Use array indexes, which can be pre-calculated from the existing table.

  ```
  DataRow[] bdArray = new DataRow[table.RowCount];

  Parallel.ForEach(table, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, row =>
  {
      DataRow newrow = BDDestino.newrow("Cars");

      newrow["Code"] = row["CODE"];
      newrow["Name"] = row["NAME"];

      // Add the new row in a pre-arranged position
      int index = table.indexOf(row);

      bdArray[index] = newrow;
   });
  ```

Or maybe it doesn't matter... you can always sort them afterwards.